# Composite key as the partition key for azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, nosql

I have a data model which as properties say A,B,C,D..G. This model has a composite key (A,B,C,D). I need to store entities of this data model into azure storage. 
Should I concatenate (A+B+C+D) and then then store the result as value of partition key (for faster retrieval operations?).

What is the best practice to choose partition key/row key in such cases?

Comment: This really doesn't have an objective answer. You haven't even shared how you need to look up your data, as your specific needs will dictate how to map your data to partition key and row key. As written, this will only yield you opinions, based on nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I concatenate (A+B+C+D) and then then store the result as value of partition key (for faster retrieval operations?)

As this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/designing-a-scalable-partitioning-strategy-for-azure-table-storage) mentioned about considering queries:

> Knowing the queries that you will be using will allow you to determine which properties are important to consider for the PartitionKey. The properties that are used in the queries are candidates for the PartitionKey.
>   **If the entity has more than two key properties, you could use a composite key of concatenated values.**

> What is the best practice to choose partition key/row key in such cases?

For a better querying performance, you need to consider the properties that used in your queries as candidates for the PartitionKey or RowKey. Here is a simple sample for you to have a better understanding of choosing the PK/RK:

There is a table called Product which has the following properties:

`| ID | Name | CategoryID | SubCategoryID | DeliveryType | Price | Status | SalesRegion |`

If the query is frequently based on `CategoryID` and `SubCategoryID`, we could combine `CategoryID_SubCategoryID` as the PartitionKey to quickly locate the specific partition and retrieve all the products within the specific Category. For the RowKey, we could just set `ID` for querying on the specific product ID or `SalesRegion_Price_DeliveryType` for filtering the products in the order of SalesRegion,Price,DeliveryType.

Additionally, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide) about designing scalable and performant Azure Storage Table.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/designing-a-scalable-partitioning-strategy-for-azure-table-storage

Looks like a good starting point.

Comment: Posting a data-modeling link isn't an answer. At best, it's a comment (and you have enough reputation to comment).